# Angular 5 template driven form unit Test - Cannot read property 'form' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-forms

Hello I'm quite new in testing.
I tried a lot to test a function but can't succeed even after reading all Stackoverflow subjects on this.
I hope you'll find a way to help me ..

Here is an extract of my html :

```
<form #myForm="ngForm">
```

Here is one of my comp:

```
@ViewChild('myForm')myForm: NgForm;
```

and I have a validate function :

```
public valider(): void {
    if (this.myForm.form.valid) {
        //doSomething
    } else {
        console.log('your form is not valid.');
    }
}
```

Finally here is the test I'm trying to run:

```
it('should send an error when the form is not valid', () => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(myComponent);
    comp = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(comp.myForm.form.invalid).toBeTruthy();
        comp.valider();
    });
});
```

The error I get is:

> Unhandled Promise rejection:', 'Cannot read property 'form' of undefined'

Thanks a lot guys

Comment: Did you import the `FormsModule` in your `TestBed`?

Comment: yes i did and i'll add my test config

Answer (score 2):

You should initialize your form after  the line

```
 fixture.detectChanges();
```

like this:

```
   component.riskForm = new NgForm([],[]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have change your component little bit.

```cpp
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('myForm') myForm: NgForm;

  valider = (): boolean => this.myForm.form.valid;
}
```

And then your tests should looks in this way:

```cpp
import {TestBed, async, ComponentFixture} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

describe('AppComponent', () => {

  const initialFormValid = true;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let component: AppComponent;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        FormsModule,
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(component).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('#valider should return forms valid state', () => {
    expect(component.valider()).toEqual(initialFormValid);
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, will try this asap =)